# Check if session exists

Tags: php

I have a script that handles a user logging in and then directs him to the index page where he has an option to log out. Here is the index page code at the moment:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
    <?php
    echo 'You are logged in as : ';
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    echo '<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

If the user logs out it still shows the text. How can I check if the session still actually exists and display a different message accordingly?

IE: Display "You are not connected" and the login link if the user is not logged in?

Comment: How about using an IF to verify if `$_SESSION['username']` is set or not and leading him to a different message if so? `if session_isvalid show this else show that`

Comment: Try `isset()` or `session_status`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {echo 'You are signed in.';}
else {echo 'You are not signed in.';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

(1). A common error is trying to end a session with out starting it first

so if your `login.php` has `session_start();` so shall your `logout.php`

if you have init.php or a file that is included. simply add it there. session start.
then you can play with session all pages.

(2). a common logout script contains this

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

(3). you are not validating the session.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {echo 'You are signed in.';}
else {echo 'You are not signed in.';}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether there's an active session by using

```
if (session_id == '') {
    // user logged out
} else {
    // user logged in
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if session_destroy does completely remove the session though.
Or alternatively you could check if ($_SESSION['username'])

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<body>
  <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
      echo "You are logged in as : {$_SESSION['username']}<p><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></p>";
    }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Just `unset($_SESSION['username']);` to log out.

Answer (score 0):

You log out will need to  have session_destroy called to clear the session.

Then like any other variable in PHP you should be able to check if it is set then show code accordingly.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['username']) {
    echo 'You are logged in as : '.$_SESSION['username'];
} else {
    echo 'You are not connected';
}
```